# is there a way to fix why i am getting these as title and description

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

i am getting this when browsing to my recent published site, can anyone help me?
[image]

althought i am adding these in index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Leading the Biotech Revolution In the Middle East"/>
    <title>Gen Middle-East & Africa</title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that picture is a google search result. You'll have to wait for Google to reindex your website in order to see the latest changes that you've made.

Comment: yes this is a google search result